# No wireless interface found

Tags: wireless

I've just got a raspberry pi. However I cannot connect to my wifi.

Here are what is in my `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicat.conf`:

```
ctrl_interfsace=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
Country=BR

Network={
        ssid="my_ssid"
        psk="my_pass"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

and here are what is in my `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) andifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

#include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wireless-essid my_ssid
wireless-key my_pass
wpa-config /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant/conf
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your wpa-supplicant.conf is running is the service or not?

Comment: Welcome.  I believe you have followed some outdated instructions by using `/etc/interfaces` for your configuration.